# R for loop around a tidyverse pipe

Tags: r

I have a dataset that examplary looks like the this:

```
var_a <- vector(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ....)
# var1 to var8 are vectors that contain pseudorandom numbers between 1 and 20 (unlike var_a not in any particular order). 
data <- data.frame(cbind(var_a, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8))
```

I would like to loop through this dataset using the column variable "var_a" (which actually contains numbers from 1-127). For each number in var_a, I would like to calculate a 8 x 8 correlation matrix of the numbers in "var1" to "var8" and store the 127 correlation matrices in a list.

I calculated the first correlation matrix for var_a=1 using the tidyverse pipe:

```
data %>%
  filter(var_a==1) %>%
  select("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8")%>%
  cor()
```

Now the hard part for me is to calculate correlation matrices for var_a=1, var_a=2, var_a=3, ...., var_a=127 and store these matrices in a list.

My attempt is the following, but I am stuck at the part where it comes to looping through and storing the correlation matrices:

```
n <- 127
corlist <- list()
for (i in 1:n) {
      data %>%
       filter(var_a==i) %>%
       select("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8") %>%
       corlist[i] <- cor()
}

"Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default"
```

Do I need to define a function for cor() first and then integrate it into the pipe and loop?

Help/ literature/ links are greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: you don't want a for loop, you want to `group_by`; given the output type desired is a `list`, you might consider `lapply` as well

Comment: for your `for` loop, I think you'll need to use `corlist[[i]]` instead of `corlist[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for-loop for this. As already mentioned in the comments you can use `group_by`.

```
library(tidyverse)

my.df.cor <- my.df %>% 
  group_by(var_a) %>%  
  nest() %>% # Stores var1 to var8 in a dataframe for each var_a
  mutate(cor = map(data, cor)) # apply the function cor() to this data for each var_a

my.df.cor 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   var_a data             cor          
#   <dbl> <list>           <list>       
# 1     1 <tibble [8 x 8]> <dbl [8 x 8]>
# 2     2 <tibble [8 x 8]> <dbl [8 x 8]>
# 3     3 <tibble [8 x 8]> <dbl [8 x 8]>
```

You recieve a tibble with 3 columns, where data stores var1 to var8 for each var_a and cor the correpsonding correlation matrix.

```
pull(my.df.cor, cor)
```

gives you the desired corlist.

You can fix your for-loop with

```
n <- 3
corlist <- list()
for (i in 1:n) {
  corlist[[i]] <- my.df %>%
    filter(var_a == i) %>%
    select("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8") %>%
    cor() 
}
```

The problem in your code is that the pipe inserts the data.frame as a first argument in the next row, but there your try to do the assignment and thus `cor()` doesn't get an argument. 
I put the assignment first and then what I want to assign to that list entry (indexed with `[[i]]` and not `[i]`)

**Data**

```
var_a <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)

set.seed(42)
my.df <- data.frame(var_a = var_a, 
                    var1 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var2 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var3 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var4 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var5 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var6 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var7 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE), 
                    var8 = sample(1:20, length(var_a), replace = TRUE))
```